# MySQL won't ORDER BY Swedish characters åäö not working even though collation is correct

Tags: mysql, collation

This query:

`SELECT customer_id, customer_name FROM customers WHERE isActive = '1' ORDER BY customer_name ASC`

Outputs:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+
| customer_id | customer_name         |
+-------------+-----------------------+
|           1 | Äname                 |
|           2 | Aname                 |
|           3 | Bname                 |
+-------------+-----------------------+
```

Why does it not sort the special swedish characters, even though I have collation `utf8_swedish_ci`

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM myDatabase WHERE name = 'customers';

+-------------+----------------------------+
| Name        | Engine   | Collation       |
+-------------+----------------------------+
| customers   | MyISAM   | utf8_swedish_ci |
+-------------+----------------------------+
```

I even tried to put the collation in my query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE isActive = 1 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci ORDER BY customer_name ASC
```

But then I get:

```
Error Code: 1253. COLLATION 'utf8_swedish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
```

Comment: What's the _column_ collation?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario `utf8_swedish_ci`

Comment: What's `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers` output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No idea about the default behaviour, but [the correct syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collate.html) is:

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name
FROM customers
WHERE isActive = '1'
ORDER BY customer_name COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci ASC
```

Comment: Use utf8mb4 is recommended.